# cv2.moments not working anymore after migrating from python27 to python 37

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, contour

I made a python script that uses opencv and the cv2.moments command to get the center of contours and other information. It was working fine until I migrated to python 3 and reinstalled opencv. Now I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opencvQuestion.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "opencvQuestion.py", line 72, in main
    referentialDetector()
  File "opencvQuestion.py", line 37, in referentialDetector
    M1 =cv2.moments(k)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

code below:

```
def referentialDetector():
    # Create mask to detect referential:
    global cnts1, blackAndWhiteImage,pts1,pts2, warpMatrix, shape, passFound
    cnts1 = cv2.findContours(np.array(blackAndWhiteImage), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # loop over the contours found in blackAndWhiteImage:
    if len(cnts1)>0:    
        cX1 = []
        cY1 = []
        for k in cnts1:
            #k = cv2.UMat(k,ranges=0)
            M1 =cv2.moments(k)
            if M1["m00"]!=0:
                print("detector4")
                cX1.append(int((M1["m10"] / M1["m00"])))
                cY1.append(int((M1["m01"] / M1["m00"])))
        print(cX1)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you by chance also switched the OpenCV version? Which version did you use before, which do you use now? Also, I'm wondering how `cnts1 = cv2.findContours(...)` and later `for k in cnts1:` and `M1 =cv2.moments(k)` could've worked anyhow in the past. `findContours` has at least two return values (for some versions even three), even for OpenCV 2.4.x. Again, could you please provide exact version information?

Comment: Hi @HansHirse, thanks for the answer. Yes, I had to reinstall opencv, so I am using V4. 2.0 for the moment.  At a certain point I had     image, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...) but the code used to work any way